# How to generate multiple dummy variables?

Tags: r

```
data1 <- data.frame(zone1 = c("A","A","A","A","B"),
                    zone2 = c("a","a","a","a","b"),
                    name = c("apple","pear","pine","banana","orange"),
                    locate = c("poor","poor","room","room","room"),
                    time = c(2000,2000,2000,2000,2001))
data2 <- data.frame(locate = c("poor","room"),
                    A = c(1,1),
                    B = c(0,1),
                    a = c(1,1),
                    b = c(0,1),
                    apple = c(1,0),
                    pear = c(1,0),
                    pine = c(0,1),
                    banana = c(0,1),
                    orange = c(0,1),
                    "2000" = c(1,1),
                    "2001" = c(0,1))
```

I tried to use spread() function to realize it.

```
dums <- data1 %>%
   select("locate", everything()) %>%
   mutate(zone1yes = 1,
          timeyes = 1,
          zone2yes = 1,
          nameyes = 1) %>%
   spread(zone1, zone1yes) %>%
   spread(time, timeyes) %>%
   spread(name, nameyes) %>%
   spread(zone2, zone2yes)
```

but I found that there are some errors and I don't know the reason.How can I realize it?

Comment: the last list in data1 (time) has 6 elements while the rest have five - is this intended?

Comment: Are you attempting to do something like one-hot encoding? I believe a dummy variable by itself can be created by converting your desired columns to factors, but it seems like you are doing more here as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` you can do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data1 %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = as.character)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -locate) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_fill = 0, id_cols = locate, 
              values_fn = function(x) as.integer(length(x) > 0))

#  locate     A     a apple `2000`  pear  pine banana     B     b orange `2001`
#  <chr>  <int> <int> <int>  <int> <int> <int>  <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int>
#1 poor       1     1     1      1     1     0      0     0     0      0      0
#2 room       1     1     0      1     0     1      1     1     1      1      1
```

Since you have data of different types we need to first convert them to one type i.e character. Get them in long format and get it back in wide by assign 1 where the value is present and 0 otherwise.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(zone1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B"), zone2 = c("a", 
"a", "a", "a", "b"), name = c("apple", "pear", "pine", "banana", 
"orange"), locate = c("poor", "poor", "room", "room", "room"), 
    time = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `melt/dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(data1), id.var = 'locate'), locate ~ value, function(x) +(length(x) > 0))
```

-output

```
#   locate 2000 2001 A B a apple b banana orange pear pine
#1:   poor    1    0 1 0 1     1 0      0      0    1    0
#2:   room    1    1 1 1 1     0 1      1      1    0    1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(zone1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B"), zone2 = c("a", 
"a", "a", "a", "b"), name = c("apple", "pear", "pine", "banana", 
"orange"), locate = c("poor", "poor", "room", "room", "room"), 
    time = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```